# LIKE is not working BUT working too

Tags: sql, sql-like

I work for a law firm. 
I have a table with all the cases, and the format is `YY-99999-ABC` where `ABC` are the Judge initials. My goal is to type just `YY-99999` without the judge initials.

So my query is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tblcase 
WHERE (CaseNm LIKE ? N'%')
```

When I select preview data, I get one row

Then when I test my code:

```
Dim caseadapter As New CWDataSetTableAdapters.CaseTableAdapter
Dim casedt As CWDataSet.CaseDataTable
Dim mCaseNum As String
mCaseNum = txtCaseNum.Text
casedt = caseadapter.GetCaseByCaseNum(mCaseNum)
If casedt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    'do my thing            

Else
    Response.Write(mCaseNum)
    Response.Write(Len(mCaseNum).ToString)
End If
```

I get now rows. 
If I change the query to CaseNum = ? and then I type the whole case number, it works.

HELP, HELP, F1, F1, F1....

Comment: Something like `WHERE (CaseNm LIKE CaseNum LIKE ? N'%')`? Well, that's not a valid SQL syntax...

Comment: It was a typo. I edited the query..

Comment: Then you perhaps should do `WHERE (CaseNm LIKE ? || N'%')`? `||` is ANSI SQL concatenation, some products have `CONCAT()` or `+` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need check SQL Lite `LIKE` syntaxis

http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like

```
SELECT FROM table_name
WHERE column LIKE 'XXXX%'
```

Here is a tutorial with aditional samples

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm

Comment: Let me add, when I test I'm using the Query builder and I use Execute Query.. It works fine..When I use preview data on the tableadapter object, it doesn't work.

Comment: are you talking about this query or the query on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

The solution was changing the WHERE clause:

WHERE RTRIM(CaseNum) LIKE ?

Then in my code:

mCaseNum = txtCaseNum.Text & "-___"

CaseNum is a VARCHAR(50)
I read this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx and there was this example:

-- Unicode pattern matching with nchar column
CREATE TABLE t (col1 nchar(30));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('Robert King');
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE col1 LIKE '% King';   -- no rows returned

-- Unicode pattern matching with nchar column and RTRIM
CREATE TABLE t (col1 nchar (30));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('Robert King');
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE RTRIM(col1) LIKE '% King';   -- returns 1 row